# Is there a way to change Property Name in JSON data

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way I can change the *column/property name* I'm returning from a JSON response through a Web API ?

Sample JSON response:

```
[
 {
  "ActualPropName1": "Value1", //change ActualPropName1 to something else
  "ActualPropName2": "Value2"
 }
]
```

I tried using Data Annotation on the Model, but, it doesn't seem to achieve what I want

```
[DisplayName("Generic Name")]
public string ActualPropName1{ get; set; }
```

Comment: You can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) with a `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "FooBar")]` applied to your property

Comment: I get no error after applying the suggestion above, but JSON still returns the actual property name.

Comment: Is this for when your serializing or deserializing? If serializing, then why not just return an anonymous object, or map it to another view model with the alternative name before serializing

Answer (score 2):

You could simply have a new property with the desired name that simply returns data from the other property.  Then hide/ignore the other:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public string ActualPropName1 { get; set; }

public string GenericName
{
    get
    {
        return ActualPropName1;
    }
}
```

Although from your example this won't work for property names like 'Generic Name'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.NET's JsonProperty

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="Your_Name")]
public string ActualPropName1{ get; set; }
```